# can we decrypt mysql encrypt data in Java

Tags: java, mysql, postgresql, encryption

```
AES_DECRYPT(AES_ENCRYPT('text','key'),'key')
```

output: text

Can we do decryption in Java?
which by using decrypt key.
(`'key'` in this case).

OR

Can we use Postgress SQL to decrypt the data of MySQL.
Details of Encryption:

MODE : Mysql Functions: Ex. AES_ENCRYPT('text','key')
Key is the in Text format, Ex. ABC
Format of Encrypted data alphanumeric Ex.acc123

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. The short answer is 'YES'. The longer answer requires some work on your side: what encryption algorithm & mode was used on encryption side, what kind of key was used, in what format is the key and is there any key derivation in place? What is the format of the encrypted data? So please edit your question, append the information and share some sample data (plaintext, key, encrypted data) to check any decryption methods.

Comment: Details of Encryption:

MODE : Mysql Functions: Ex. AES_ENCRYPT('text','key')
Key is the in Text format, Ex. ABC
Format of Encrypted data alphanumeric Ex.acc123

Comment: Thnaks for the reply.
Please let me know if you can answer in details with Exampple.

Comment: Thanks, now just the encrypted data is missing (what is the cipherdata when encrypting 'text' with 'key'). And 'key' ist just 3 letters short?

Comment: Hey@MichaelFehr Thanks for reply 
I am getting below exception now.

Comment: Exception in thread "main" javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Given final block not properly padded.